# Issues with Hibernate HQL select query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Below is the code snipped for my POJO and the HQL query to retrieve the roles for the given account. For some reason the HQL query results in a '0' rows selected even though a match exists in the DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_roles")

public class AccountRoles implements Serializable {

     @Column(name = "roleName")
     private String roleName;

     @Column(name = "accountNumber")
     private String accountNumber;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "iD")
     private int iD;

     public String getRoleName() { return roleName; }
     public void setRoleName(String roleName){ this.roleName = roleName;}

     public String getAccountNumber() { return accountNumber;}
     public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber){ this.accountNumber = accountNumber;}

     public int getId() { return iD;}
     public void setId(int iD){ this.iD = iD; }

}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AccountRoles getKey(String accountNum, String roleName) throws Exception{
    String sql = "from AccountRoles where accountNumber= :accountNumber AND roleName= :roleName";
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List<AWSAccountRoles> accountRoles;
    try{
        accountRoles = session.createQuery(sql)
                .setString("accountNumber",accountNum)
                .setString("roleName",roleName)
                .list();
        if(accountRoles.size() >0 ){
            System.out.println(" found at least 1 row");
            return accountRoles.get(0);
        }else{
            System.out.println("returned empty list");
            return null;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
```

DDL for the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_roles` (
  `iD` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountNumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `roleName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `accountNumber` (`accountNumber`,`roleName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Need some help with debugging why the query results in an empty list ( or '0' rows )

Comment: Try executing hibernate generated SQL.

Comment: have you checked your arguments value which you are sending dynamically?

Comment: @iNan: Executing the hibernate generated SQL works just fine. I also printed the the dynamic values that i'm passing in, just to double check and they are right as well.

Comment: check the db connection config. Are you connecting to the same DB?

Comment: As @iNan mentioned, you can specify in Hibernate config files to output SQL that is executed, see from there if maybe getKey method gets called with parameters order reversed (account number is second), apostrophes are missing or whatever happens...

Comment: Yes I am. In fact I did an insert to this table programmatically and it works fine. Its only when I'm using HQL to query that I see this issue.

Comment: I'm logging the hibernate generated SQL and did try that, all good there

Comment: Just for some more context, I did try the HQL select for a different table in the same DB and was able to do the lookup. Was wondering if it has anything to do with the mapping of the POJO since it worked for a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The issue that I was facing was a result of recursive @Transactional events. Once I separated out the calls , the query and insert work fine .